# Extra argument in call in self.init Swift 2.2

Tags: swift2, nsdata, nscoding

I've been searching for this error and reading various stackoverflow, Apple documentation and blog answers but I'm still having issues. I have a class conforming to NSData and NSCoding for which of 3 of 6 properties will be stored. When calling self.init in the required convenience init, I get an error "Extra argument 'groomedStatus' in call," even though the self.init signature matches init exactly (I copied and pasted). This is the relevant code:

```
class Trail: NSObject, NSCoding {
var name: String
var difficulty: Difficulty
var haveSkied: Bool
var season: Season = .winter
var open: String?
var groomedStatus: String?

init(name: String, difficulty: Difficulty, haveSkied: Bool, season: Season, open: String?, groomedStatus: String?) {
    self.name = name
    self.difficulty = difficulty
    self.haveSkied = haveSkied
    self.season = season
    self.open = open
    self.groomedStatus = groomedStatus
}

required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    let haveSkied = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("haveSkied") as! Bool
    let open = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("open") as? String
    let groomedStatus = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("groomedStatus") as? String


    self.init(name: String, difficulty: Difficulty, haveSkied: Bool, season: Season, open: String?, groomedStatus: String?) {
        self.name = name
        self.difficulty = difficulty
        self.haveSkied = haveSkied
        self.season = season
        self.open = open
        self.groomedStatus = groomedStatus
    }

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeBool(haveSkied, forKey: "haveSkied")
    aCoder.encodeObject(open, forKey: "open")
    aCoder.encodeObject(groomedStatus, forKey: "groomedStatus")
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure? This is a compiler error, so I didn't uninstall and reinstall the app from the simulator, and I have tried Command B to build it several times after making changes.

Comment: Ah, that was just something silly I was trying because I ran out of ideas. I'll change it back to the original.

Comment: The error message is a bit misleading. The problem is the nested `init` definition in the `init(coder...` method. That cannot work at all. For example you have to pass a real string for `name`, not the type `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem results from how you call `self.init()`. The way you're doing it in your code is essentially an attempt to redefine it, which makes no sense to the compiler. This is how you should be calling `self.init()` in your convenience initializer.

```
self.init(name: "yourActualNameString", difficulty: Difficulty(), haveSkied: true, season: .winter, open: "yourActualOpenString", groomedStatus: "yourActualGroomedStatusString")
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I saved every property of the class using encodeObject and used decodeObjectForKey to pass in the actual values to self.init.